# Django mysql database not accepting date format

Tags: mysql, json, django, date

This is the json object I'm sending to the server (Http post)

> {"user_id":"91*********","user_name":"********","birthday":"1994-26-01","location":"New Delhi, India"}

I get an internal server error at the client. On checking the server it says:

> HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST Content-Type: application/json Vary: Accept
>   Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
>
> {
>       "birthday": [
>           "Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY[-MM[-DD]]"
>       ] }

But when the db stores the dates, it saves it in the same format I do, then where am I going wrong? And in what format should I send the value in the date field ?

Note: I'm a noob at django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message says that you need to pass the date in the YYYY-MM-DD format (4 digits for year, 2 for month, 2 for day). Instead, as we can see from your example you are passong "1994-26-01" which is YYYY-DD-MM (since 26 can only be day). That's why you are receiving the error.

You need to fix the datetime format you pass, YYYY-DD-MM is not valid in any case.