# Not able to catch invalid date 31st - feb in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Not able to catch the exception with invalid date like 31st Feb. It is not even coming in validate method. This field is in nested model serializer.

[{'dob': ['Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY[-MM[-DD]].'],

Answer (score 0):

Try to read here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#date-and-time-formatting

Generally your message is difficult to understand. You probably have an error when you send a request (curl, Postman), and maybe you just pass the date in the wrong format, which jango tells you.
That seems to be a similar problem was solved:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28262273/9018283